# How to remove border from menuitem?

Tags: wpf

I have created code using mutil menuitem, but I can not remove the border.

[image: Link Image].

How can I remove the menuitem border WPF?

Code MainWindow.xaml below

```
<Window x:Class="TestMutilColumnMenu.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestMutilColumnMenu"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="MenuItem1" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush"  Value="DarkGray"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin"  Value="1,1,1,1"/>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Menu>
        <MenuItem x:Name="tesst" Header="nane" >
            <MenuItem.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    </Grid>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </MenuItem.ItemsPanel>
            <MenuItem Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  Header="Item 1" Style="{StaticResource  MenuItem1}">
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <Image Source="/res/Image.png"/>
                </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Header="Item 2" Style="{StaticResource  MenuItem1}">
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <Image Source="/res/Image.png"/>
                </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Header="Item 3" Style="{StaticResource  MenuItem1}"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Header="Item 4" Style="{StaticResource  MenuItem1}"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Header="Item 5" Style="{StaticResource  MenuItem1}">
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <Image Source="/res/Image.png"/>
                </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Header="Item 6" Style="{StaticResource  MenuItem1}">
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <Image Source="/res/Image.png"/>
                </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Header="Item 7" Style="{StaticResource  MenuItem1}">
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <Image Source="/res/Image.png"/>
                </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Header="Item 8" Style="{StaticResource  MenuItem1}"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Header="Item 9" Style="{StaticResource  MenuItem1}"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Header="Item 10" Style="{StaticResource  MenuItem1}"></MenuItem>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a custom `ControlTemplate` for the root `MenuItem`. This is the default one except for the `Width` of the `Rectange` which I have changed from `1` to `0`:

```
<MenuItem x:Name="tesst" Header="nane" >
    <MenuItem.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Border x:Name="templateRoot" SnapsToDevicePixels="true"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Control.BorderThickness}"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Control.Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Control.BorderBrush}">
                <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" ContentSource="Icon"
                          SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="16" Height="16" Margin="3"/>
                    <Path x:Name="GlyphPanel" Data="M 0,0 L 4,3.5 L 0,7 Z" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Margin="3"
                          Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Center" Fill="{TemplateBinding Control.Foreground}"/>
                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" ContentSource="Header" RecognizesAccessKey="true"
                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}"
                          SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="true" Focusable="false"
                           PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.MenuPopupAnimationKey}}"
                           Placement="Bottom"
                           IsOpen="{Binding IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                           PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=templateRoot}">
                        <Border x:Name="SubMenuBorder" Background="#FFF0F0F0" BorderBrush="#FF999999" BorderThickness="1" Padding="2">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="SubMenuScrollViewer" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=MenuScrollViewer, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}}}">
                                <Grid RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                    <Canvas Height="0" Width="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                        <Rectangle Name="OpaqueRect" Height="{Binding ElementName=SubMenuBorder, Path=ActualHeight}"
                                                   Width="{Binding ElementName=SubMenuBorder, Path=ActualWidth}"
                                                   Fill="{Binding ElementName=SubMenuBorder, Path=Background}"/>
                                    </Canvas>
                                    <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="0" Margin="29,2,0,2" Fill="#FFD7D7D7"/>
                                    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle"
                                                    KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="true"
                                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Border>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="MenuItem.IsSuspendingPopupAnimation" Value="true">
                    <Setter TargetName="PART_Popup" Property="Popup.PopupAnimation" Value="None"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Value="{x:Null}" Property="MenuItem.Icon">
                    <Setter TargetName="Icon" Property="UIElement.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="MenuItem.IsChecked" Value="true">
                    <Setter TargetName="GlyphPanel" Property="UIElement.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    <Setter TargetName="Icon" Property="UIElement.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="MenuItem.IsHighlighted" Value="true">
                    <Setter TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#3D26A0DA" Property="Border.Background"/>
                    <Setter TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FF26A0DA" Property="Border.BorderBrush"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsEnabled" Value="false">
                    <Setter TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FF707070" Property="TextElement.Foreground"/>
                    <Setter TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="#FF707070" Property="Shape.Fill"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger SourceName="SubMenuScrollViewer" Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false">
                    <Setter TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding ElementName=SubMenuScrollViewer, Path=VerticalOffset}" Property="Canvas.Top"/>
                    <Setter TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding ElementName=SubMenuScrollViewer, Path=HorizontalOffset}" Property="Canvas.Left"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </MenuItem.Template>
    <MenuItem.ItemsPanel>
     ...
```

Comment: if change MenuItem to Contextmenu border not remove. How do remove boder when using ContextMenu,

Comment: You should replace the `MenuItem` named "tesst" in your example with mine. You need to modify the `ControlTemplate` exactly like I showed you.